# Type 'AngularFireList<{}>' is not assignable to type 'FirebaseListObservable<any>'

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, ionic3, angularfire2

I'm working on an Ionic 3 app, and I'm trying connect my app to firebase database. but it keeps telling me this:

```
Type 'AngularFireList<{}>' is not assignable to type 'FirebaseListObservable<any>'.
Property '$ref' is missing in type 'AngularFireList<{}>'.
(property) AddEmployeePage.employeesList: FirebaseListObservable<any>
```

I'm trying to add data to my database and it all goes wrong, here is my typescript code:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import { AngularFireModule } from 'angularfire2';
import { AngularFireDatabase } from 'angularfire2/database';
import { FirebaseListObservable } from 'angularfire2/database-deprecated';
import { EmployeesPage } from './../employees/employees';

@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-add-employee',
  templateUrl: 'add-employee.html',
})
export class AddEmployeePage {

  employeesList: FirebaseListObservable<any>;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, public angDb: AngularFireDatabase) {
    this.employeesList = angDb.list('/emloyeesionic');
  }

  addNewEmployee(fname, lname, pos, comp)
  {
    this.employeesList.push({
      fname: fname,
      lname: lname,
      position: pos,
      company: comp,
    }).then(newEmployee => {
      this.navCtrl.push(EmployeesPage)
    }, error => {
      console.log(error);
    });
  }
}
```

Here is a screenshot for the error in my IDE
[image]

Comment: I didn't add that in the constructor. Thanks for this post!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think what you need is

```
employeesList: AngularFireList<any>;
```

instead of

```
employeesList: FirebaseListObservable<any>;
```

Based on the example given [here](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/rtdb/lists.md#deleting-the-entire-list)

Comment: Oh my god, that was a miss focusing. The whole day I was on the documentation and I didn't gave it the chance. Thank you really.

Comment: Docs need to be a bit more clear on this. Can I have a custom type such as `shirts` as in the docs here https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/rtdb/lists.md#create-a-list-binding